# Why was :contains not included in the css3 spec?

Tags: css3

There was apparently a `:contains` selector proposed at some point, but was dropped. I've searched all over, but I can't seem to find anything which gives any more info than [this](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors).

Why was this selector not included in the css3 spec?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about **[webmastering as defined in the FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not included in CSS3 for a few reasons. A little more about reasons can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781141/why-doesnt-the-selector-h3nth-child1containsa-work/4781167#4781167

The best alternative to use is [CSS3 Substring Matching Attribute Selectors](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css3-substring-matching-attribute-selectors) which allow wild cards